# AppLovin AppDiscovery

Tags: mobile-ad-mediation, applovin

My team uses AdMob for monetization. We want to plug in AppLovin as a mediation network. One criteria that really matters to us is that AppLovin provide creative controls (e.g. control to opt out of video ads). Can someone please help confirm if AppLovin AppDiscovery provides that functionality?

Appreciate all the help!

I researched online and tried contacting the AppLovin support team.

Comment: Like what is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: My team and I need to know if those controls are available in AppLovin. Do you know?

Comment: Is it a app in playstore or something?

Comment: If this is so then I have to call like moderators because it is advertising the product not like test them if you want them to get tested then hire a user tester You can go to like usertesting.com

Comment: I just wanted confirmation on whether the product has the above said controls. That’s about it. If you don’t have the info, that’s fine. I can look elsewhere or wait for someone who has worked on the product

Comment: reach out directly to AppLovin's support team or refer to their official documentation.

Comment: Tried that - info not available. Hence, checking over here in case anyone is a user.